# how to set user control style attribute?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

how can i set style attribute in code behind c#?

thanks
niall

Comment: this.userControl1.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A user control isn't directly converted to a single HTML object - it is a collection of objects grouped together, therefore you can't set its "style".

If you want to hide it, then it should have a `Visible` attribute which you can set to false, however, this means that it won't be rendered to the page at all, and so subsequently can't be made visible in client code.

Answer (score 6):

Basically like this

```
Control.Style.Add("background-color", "red");
```

Or like this for any other attribute:

```
Control.Attributes.Add("style", "color: red;");
```